# Using Entity manager and JPA, returns object only

Tags: java, jpa

When i run the following code it was return only object list. i want the list in vehicle. what is the error in my code?

My Dao Class Is:

```
public class VehicleDao {

HibernateTemplate template;  
private EntityManager emManager;

@PersistenceContext
public void setEm(EntityManager emManager) {
    this.emManager = emManager;
}
public List<Vehicle> getVehicleDataUsing_Sp()
{
Properties prop= new Properties();
    try {
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream("E:\\spring4AndHibernate5\\src\\Query.properties");
        prop.load(input);
        Query query = emManager.createNativeQuery(prop.getProperty("vehicleQuery"));
        List<Vehicle> list = query.getResultList();
        return list;
        }
}
```

Comment: Please maintain the catch Block and finally (Optional )

Comment: @Manihtraa please don't edit your code according to answers. It makes harder to understand your actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to define the result class in your native query definition (use `resultClass=Vehicle.class` where you have defined your named query)

and/or

you need to map the native class when using createNamedQuery (use `createNativeQuery(prop.getProperty("vehicleQuery"), Vehicle.class)`).

Answer (score 1):

You can't return `List<Vehicle>` when you have specified the return type as `void`.

Try this instead:

```
public List<Vehicle> getVehicleDataUsing_Sp()
```

And you also need to add a `catch` block after the `try` block, like this:

```
catch(Exception e)
{
}
```

Comment: List<Vehicle> list = query.getResultList(); when this line execute value of list is array object. i want vehicle object list. you saying only return type related issue but i want datatype related fix.

Comment: Oh I see. I'll rectify it. Just give me some time :)

Answer (score 1):

Because it's a native query, it doesn't know what to try mapping it to, unless you tell it.

Try:

```
Query query = emManager.createNativeQuery(prop.getProperty("vehicleQuery"), Vehicle.class);
```